# When you are going to compliment a lovely place

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine you and your love get into a posh and romantic restaurant. You feel amazing and you want to compliment the restaurant. Does the following self-made sentence work here:

> - What a poetical environment.
> - What a poetical atmosphere.

If yes is it natural and if not what would a native speaker say instead to convey the same message?

Comment: "How romantic!" "So romantic!" Why wouldn't you just use the word romantic? This is not the correct use of the word "poetical."

Comment: Actually whereas in my mother language the adjective "poetical", sometimes, can be substituted with "romantic" in such a case, I was going to find out if the adjective "poetical" can be figuratively used in English in the meaning of "romantic". @TeacherKSHuang

Comment: What about the word "idyllic"? Its true meaning is 'picturesque in a rustic (country) sense', but it has very strong romantic overtones. If you have ever seen the Manet painting "Le Déjeuner sur l'herbe" you'll know what I mean. This might not be appropriate for a 'posh', formal restaurant but would serve well for a more intimate locale.